# Equivalent of angularjs $compile to typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Im new here with angular typescript, using angular 8.

I have a previous code of angularJS and converting it to angular 8.
Im having difficulty converting a line of angularjs code in typescript.

```
var myContent = $compile($($(element).data('contentwrapper'))[0].children)(scope);
```

this is the full function

```
    app.directive('loadManageRecordsFilter', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            //Initialize the save search popover
            var myContent = $compile($($(element).data('contentwrapper'))[0].children)(scope);
            $(element).popover({
                html: true,
                placement: 'left',
                content: myContent,
                title: 'Filter Records'
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

it has a popover and needs to position from the button element.

Your idea will be a great help

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're facing here? Can you share a Stackblitz? Please elaborate a little on what you tried and how it fails.

Comment: ill add detail. thanks.